# cmake with openmpi produces "mpi.h not found"

Tags: c++, cmake, osx-mavericks, openmpi

I have a very simple "Hello world" program that compiles with mpic++. I also have the following `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(Hello_world)

add_executable(hello.e main.cpp)

# Require MPI for this project:
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
include_directories(MPI_INCLUDE_PATH)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FLAGS} ${MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS})
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS} ${MPI_LINK_FLAGS})
target_link_libraries(hello.e ${MPI_LIBRARIES}
```

This cmake file works perfectly on Linux, but not on Mac OS X Mavericks. On Mavericks I get: "`mpi.h not found`" error.

Here is the output of `cmake .` showing that it found the `openmpi`:

```
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 5.1.0.5030040
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 5.1.0.5030040
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found MPI_C: /opt/local/lib/openmpi-devel-mp/libmpi.dylib  
-- Found MPI_CXX: /opt/local/lib/openmpi-devel-mp/libmpi.dylib  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/sleepyhead/work/MPI_TEST
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `include_directories(MPI_INCLUDE_PATH)` to `include_directories(${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})`

Comment: `ld: unknown option: -headerpad_max_install_names;-Wl` that's next error, after I did the change. I wonder why does it work effortlessly on Linux?